# jQuery not working properly in Laravel 8 with DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am working on a Laravel project and I'm having some trouble using JS datatables. I have this script on my blade file.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#clientsTable').DataTable({
                'search' : false
            });
        });
    </script>
```

It is not working though and the console says that the '$ is not defined'. If I try to access '$' in the console though it looks like jQuery is loaded. So I guess that the function call to activate Datatables is called before jQuery is loaded.

In my app.js file I have this.

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('admin-lte');
```

And the bootstrap.js file is supposed to load jQuery. I have temporarily solved this by explicitly calling jQuery on my blade file as well, but then I have problems with BS modals because jQuery is called twice. Can anyone help me? I'm using Laravel 8.

I have also checked and in my main layout file the app.js file is not being called using defer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation for a comment, so posting as an answer.

You said app js file loads the bootstrap.js, which is okay.
Can you check the bootstrap.js file itself (should be in the resources/js folder) and see if you're calling the jquery before the require('bootstrap') itself?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. jQuery is called before require('bootstrap').

Comment: Alright. You also said the $ works otherwise, so that means the app.js jquery loads. So that means (as you said as well), the data table loads before the jquery. Could you view the page source on the browser and check if the import of app.js script happens before or after the datatable init?

Comment: Okay, I thought about this as well. I put a defer on my call to the datatables js file, so that it always loads last. When I do a hard reload it looks like app.js is called first and then datatables.js. On a normal reload though the datatables.js file is loaded from the memory cache and for some reason it is loaded before app.js. On both cases though, the same error comes up in the console.

Comment: Okay. Well that didn't make anything easier. app.js > datatable.js > your custom script. This should be the proper order. If it's that already, then there is something else which is being overlooked.